# Associative law is not self evident

Tags: group-theory

The statement:

"It is important to understand that the associative law is not
self-evident; indeed, if $a*b=a/b$ for positive numbers $a$ and $b$
then, in general, $(a*b)*c\ne a*(b*c)$." - p. 3, A. Beardon, Algebra
and Geometry.

I am unclear as to how to take the assumption $a*b=a/b$. Does he mean
that we suppose, as an alternative (thought experiment),
that $a*b :=
a/b$ and substitute
$(a/b)$ for each $(a*b)$ and prove the inequality of the resulting
statement? Or, should one notice that
$a*b=a/b$ is true when $b=1$, but then note that the domain was
assumed to be
 $\mathbb{R}_+$, therefore $(a*b)*c \ne a*(b*c)$ in general?

Comment: You take it as an example.

Comment: An addendum that could be added to most of the answers is that mathematicians very rarely write $*$ for ordinary multiplication. For expressions $X$ and $Y$, "$X$ times $X$" is commonly written $XY$, $X\cdot Y$ or $X\times y$ but seldom $X*Y$. $*$ is a programming language thing.

Comment: $*$ isn't multiplication here. The author is asking you to suppose you have a group where the binary operation (written $*$) is the division operation.   The author could have said, "suppose $*$ is $/$, i.e., division."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are basically right in your guesses. What is being emphasized is that not all binary operations (i.e. things that take two inputs from your set and return a third element of the set) that one can define are necessarily associative *just* because they are binary operations. In this example they are saying that if you **define** the particular example of a binary operation, to which they give the name $*$, on the set $\Bbb R^+$, as in this example, i.e. $a*b={a\over b}$, then

$$(a*b)*c={{a\over b}\over c}={a\over bc}$$

and

$$a*(b*c)={a\over {b\over c}}={ac\over b}$$

by direct computation.

At this point you might object and say "but doesn't $*$ mean multiplication?" If so, you can replace the symbol $*$ by another one if it helps you, $\oplus$ is a nice one as well, the point is it's the binary operation we've defined, no matter what it looks like on paper as a symbol.

Now, by definition two real numbers, $x,y\in\Bbb R$, the definition of equality is

> $$x=y\iff x-y=0$$

and given two fractions, ${p\over q}, {r\over s}\in\Bbb R^+$ the definition of equality is

> $${p\over q}={r\over s}\iff ps-qr=0.$$

In your case:

$${a\over bc}-{ac\over b}=0$$
$$\iff {a\over bc}={ac\over b}$$
$$\iff ab-abc^2=0$$
$$\iff ab=abc^2$$

for **every** $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^+$, however this condition clearly **requires** $c^2=1$ which is *only* true for $c=1$ over the positive real numbers, so the operation is not associative, because the relation only holds for a **single** positive real number, $c=1$, rather than **all** positive reals.

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you Adam!

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen to a question.

Answer (score 7):

Here, the $*$ represents an arbitrary binary operation, not multiplication as you think. The definition of $*$ is a map $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ that is *defined* by $*(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}$. Now, $a*b$ is just an alternate way of representing $*(a,b)$.

Now why isn't $*$ associative? Well, we have $(a*b)*c=(a/b)*c=(a/b)/c=\frac{a}{bc}$, and $a*(b*c)=a*(b/c)=a/(b/c)=\frac{ac}{b}$, hence $(a*b)*c \not= a*(b*c)$.

Comment: Fujoyaki, not sure how it happened, but your answer, which was more timely than some others but didn't show up until much later upon a third refresh of the browswer. Very nice answer and wording, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think you're assuming that * means multiplication. But in this situation it represents a general binary operation, and in particular, division.

Comment: Thank you anon, you nailed it. I could only give the answer to one (due to shortcomings in this SE system IMHO), but I surely appreciate your help (and fast!).

Comment: @Joe Ah yes, the only-one-answer "shortcoming." That is a fight you will not win. (To give the policy its due, I do think it's helped keep SE sites remain *Q&A* focused rather than devolving into discussion forums.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, without making any assumptions, $\ast$ stands just for a group operation. In your cited example, it is *defined* to be division. Therefore, in this case, $(a \ast b) \ast c = (a/b)/c \neq a/(b/c) = a \ast (b \ast c)$, except for trivial cases.

Comment: herrsimon, I am torn because you gave the answer succinctly and, as I now see, correctly, with the case worked out. I'd give you the answer too if I could. I was helped by some of the additional details Adam provided. Clearly, you also provided the answer. I wish this was just a points system and not only one getting the answer credit. All three responses were the answer, just varying levels of comprehensiveness/length. I appreciate succinct too! My intent was to give you two points, anon 1, and Adam the answer. Alas, somehow I gave you one and anon 2 and I can't yet change that.